# How to check values of too many number of radio buttons groups to enable the submit button?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have too many number of radio buttons inside a form with different names, and I want to enable the submit button if only all radio button groups are checked ( in other words each radio button name has been checked).
How Can I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to collect all radio group `name`'s. Then you need to iterate over all radio groups and check if they all are checked. For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var names = [];
        var allChecked = true;
        $('input:radio').each(function(){
            if(names.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) === -1) {
                names.push($(this).attr('name'));
            }
        });
        for(var i = 0, cnt = names.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            if(!$('input[name="' + names[i] + '"]').is(':checked')) {
                allChecked = false;
            }
        }
        if(allChecked) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    })
});​
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/FxD6L/1/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: Actually, when I try that, I got this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=test_answer[purpose_id]]

Comment: This is because you have brackets in your names. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="a">
   <input type="radio" name="a">
   <input type="radio" name="a">
   <input type="radio" name="a">|
   <input type="radio" name="b">
   <input type="radio" name="b">
   <input type="radio" name="b">
   <input type="radio" name="b">|
   <input type="radio" name="c">
   <input type="radio" name="c">
   <input type="radio" name="c">
   <input type="radio" name="c">
   <input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$().ready(function(){
   $('form input:radio').change(function(){
        var rButtons = $('form input:radio');
        var rValues = $.map(rButtons, function(e, i) {
               return $('input[name="'+ e.name +'"]').is(':checked');
        }).toString().split(',');
        // -1 for if no match
        if($.inArray('false', rValues) == -1) {
            $('#mysubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

Updated this answer to match ur requirements.
[FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WsgFx/5/)